# Refresh page after onclick in <a></a>

Tags: refresh

I have the following code:

```
<a onclick="removeCart('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');" name="remove[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]"  class="button"><span>Remove</span></a>
```

When I click the "Remove" button, which is shown with the above code, I want the "onclick" to be executed (which is executed), and after that, the page to be refreshed. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reload the page using javascript you can do:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

So to reload after the onclick simply add that to the end of onclick, eg:

```
onclick="removeCart('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');window.location.href=window.location.href;"
```

edit: full code with delay

```
<a onclick="removeCart('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href', 100)" name="remove[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]"  class="button"><span>Remove</span></a>
```

Comment: Just tried it, but sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Strange... Any thoughts why it's like that?

Comment: Not sure... maybe sometimes there's an error in the removeCart function? See if any errors come up in the console.

Comment: It's working fine every time, but the thing is that sometimes the page reloads, and afterwards the "onclick" is executed. Is there any way I can sequence it, so first the "onclick" is executed, and after that, the page to be reloaded?

Comment: It should do it in order... maybe try setTimout("window.location.href=window.location.href", 100) which will delay the refresh by 100ms

Comment: Can you please paste me the whole code, because if I just replace your code, it's not working :(

Comment: I think thats probably because the double quotes in setTimeout where closing the original quotes, try the complete thing I edited into the answer

Comment: Yeap, it seams to be working far by now, thank a lot to all of you, especially you Shawabawa.

Answer (score 1):

First answer is correct, also you could use

```
 window.location.reload();
```

Comment: It's working this way as well, but the thing is that sometimes the page reloads, and afterwards the "onclick" is executed. Is there any way I can sequence it, so first the "onclick" is executed, and after that, the page to be reloaded?

Comment: Doesn't your removeCart() function performs asynchronous call (AJAX for example)? In this case you must put reloading code into ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

you can resubmit the page to itself by triggering the submit of an input field for instance.
Assuming that your hyperlink got the id **nextLink** and you got an input with id **submitMe** you can do :

```
 $("#nextLink").click(function () {

            //setting the url of the action target (your page or controller)
            $('#submitMe').attr('action', '/MySection/MyPage.php');
            $("#submitMe").submit();
        });
```