# How to refresh my php page: onclick

Tags: php, refresh

I need to refresh my php. page after my onclick, but in the on click i have to send some values
Is it posible?

this is my code:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="" onclick="this.href='insertaCotizacion.php?pais=' + document.getElementById('pais').value + '&proyecto=' + document.getElementById('proyecto').value + '&notas=' + document.getElementById('notas').value + '&formapago=' + document.getElementById('formapago').value + '&fechaentrega=' + document.getElementById('fechaentrega').value + '&flete=' + document.getElementById('flete').value + '&instalacion=' + document.getElementById('instalacion').value + '&venta=' + document.getElementById('venta').value + '&total=' + document.getElementById('total').value; return true/*I WANNA REFRESH MY PAGE HERE*/">Realizar</a> //
```

I saw [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835261/refresh-page-after-onclick-in-a-a), but i dont understand

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.reload();` to reload the page.

Comment: Where i have to use it? on my onclick? my onclick already does something

Comment: Wrap everything it does right now into a function, and then make it do what it does now and include `location.reload()` afterwards.
Next up just call that function onclick. `onclick="theFunctionToCall ();"` like that.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to reload page with params use `window.location.href`

Example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function reloadUrl(){
     var url=insertaCotizacion.php?pais=' + document.getElementById('pais').value + '&proyecto=' + document.getElementById('proyecto').value + '&notas=' + document.getElementById('notas').value + '&formapago=' + document.getElementById('formapago').value + '&fechaentrega=' + document.getElementById('fechaentrega').value + '&flete=' + document.getElementById('flete').value + '&instalacion=' + document.getElementById('instalacion').value + '&venta=' + document.getElementById('venta').value + '&total=' + document.getElementById('total').value;
     window.location.href=url;

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:reloadUrl();">LINK</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```